# How to search and replace all tags in HTML file using Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I am not trying to do anything to the content (at least not yet.) What I am trying to do is search for specific tags and replace them with another one.

I got this HTML that is filled with these tags with the SAME ID (I know this is horrible!)

```
<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #1
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #2
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #3
</div>

.
.
.

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #49
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #50
</div>
```

I am trying to write a function that would search for every `<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">` and delete it **without** deleting the inner text. And then search for every `</div>` and delete it as well. Then, wrap the entire thing in a `<p>` tags.

The result should be something like this:

```
<p>
some text here #1

some text here #2

some text here #3

.
.
.

some text here #49

some text here #50
</p>
```

Comment: Is this the entire content of the HTML? Are there other `div`s, other elements with `dir="rtl"`, or other elements with `id="book-container"`?

Comment: Only elements with `dir="rtl"`.

Comment: If you have any `<p>` tags in content that is not replaced the resulting html will be invalid if you wraup the whole lot in a `<p>`. Or do you want the replaced content moved out of the regular flow? Next question, why do you want to do this, if purely for styling reasons CSS can handle it?

Comment: I do not have any <p> inside the content. I am not sure about your second question. I just want the content to be placed in one <p> tags instead of div. I am doing this as I am cleaning up html for a book.

Comment: Is **everything** wrapped in `<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">` nodes or are there other sibling nodes. E.g : `<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">Something</div><div>A sibling</div><div dir="rtl" id="book-container">Something Else</div>`

Comment: No, it is just like in the question. Many div tags with the same ID and different content. I want to merge all of them into one <p> tag.

Comment: Are these elements the **only** thing in the `body` tag? Are they wrapped in any other common tag? Do you want line breaks between what was the elements?  Is ther HTML **inside** the elements you want to retain?

Comment: Yes, they are the only things the body. No, they are not wrapped in any other tag. No need for breaks. Yes, there is html elements that I'd like to retain inside of these tags.

Comment: I see your comment here and on Jon P's answer, but if you put them all in a single p tag the whitespace will be folded together and you'll have a single very long line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach to the problem with a comment explaining each step.

I took a sample of three elements and enclosed them in a `body` tag:

```js
/* Create a paragraph element where the content will be displayed */
const theParagraph = document.createElement("p");
/* Choosing the elements */
const soWrongNodes = document.querySelectorAll("#book-container")
/* For each element, put its content in the paragraph then remove the 
element */
soWrongNodes.forEach(soWrongNode => {
  theParagraph.innerHTML += soWrongNode.innerHTML;
  theParagraph.innerHTML += "<br>";
  soWrongNode.remove();
})
/* Append the paragraph element to the body */
document.body.appendChild(theParagraph);
```

```html
<body>
  <div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
    some text here #1
  </div>
  <div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
    some text here #2
  </div>
  <div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
    some text here #3
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a [fiddle.js](https://jsfiddle.net/mkx7ty16/16/) where you can see the result.

Comment: Sure thing. This solution caters for that as well.

Comment: If someone is reading this and would like to maintain any html tags inside the soon-to-be-removed tags, use innerHTML instead of interText. Edit: Thank you for the edit!

Comment: You could skip the 2nd loop here, just append the content to the new `p` element in the first loop, declaring the new element before the loop.

Comment: @JonP , if you don't mind explaining why could I skip the 2nd loop?

Comment: @JonP Good point.
and CaptainCustard, hopefully this edited code will help you visualize it.

Comment: Mind that this one does not preserve the element orders

Comment: @DDomen May you give an example?

Comment: Sure: take one of the other answers HTML code from the snippets and plug in with this JS code, all the  `#book-container` text will appear at the end of the document, regardless of their previous order

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the order of the text inside the #book-container elements. It all depends on where someone would want to append the paragraph. I chose the body element, but you could simply append it to any existing element.

Comment: I mean, if you have `<div #book-container>Text 1</div><p>Text 2</p><div #book-container>Text 3</div>` your final result is: `<p>Text2</p><p>Text 1<br/>Text 3</p>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228499/discussion-between-bavshehata-and-ddomen).

Answer (score 0):

[replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) is probably what you are after here

```js
//Get the offending nodes
let candidates = document.querySelectorAll("#book-container");
//And iterate them
for(let i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++){
  //Get a node
  let candidate = candidates[i];
  //Create a replacement, could use createTextNode if you don't want to wrap it
  //Or change the element, add styles etc if you want.
  let replacement = document.createElement("p");
  //Set the inner text from the node
  replacement.innerText = candidate.innerText;
  //Replace the node
  candidate.replaceWith(replacement);  
}
```

```html
<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #1
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #2
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #3
</div>

<p>Some Other</p>
<p>Content</p>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #49
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #50
</div>
```

You may also want to investigate `textContent` and [how it differs from `innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)

Comment: This puts a <p> around each one instead of only one <p> around the entire thing.

Comment: Is there any content that is not in a `<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">` that would lie at the same level of the document? If so do you need to maintain the flow of the document? Using for example the random `p` tags in my example?

Comment: Yes, I need to maintain the flow (if you mean order) of the document. No, there is not any other content with a div tag nor the same ID.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED:

```js
function removeElements() {
  let parent = document.getElementById('book-container').parentElement;
  let elems = Array.from(parent.children);
  let texts = []
  let group = []
  
  let replace = () => {
    if (group.length) {
      let groupElem = document.createElement('p');
      groupElem.innerHTML = group.map(e => e.innerText).join('<br/>')
      group[0].replaceWith(groupElem);
      for (let i = 1; i < group.length; ++i) {
        group[i].remove();
      }
    }
    group = []
  };
  
  for (let elem of elems) {
    if (elem.tagName == 'DIV' && elem.id == 'book-container') { group.push(elem); }
    else { replace(); }
  }
  
  replace();
}

removeElements()
```

```html
<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #1
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #2
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #3
</div>

<p>Some Other</p>
<p>Content</p>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #49
</div>

<div dir="rtl" id="book-container">
some text here #50
</div>
```

Comment: If I use remove() on it, wouldn't it remove the content as well?

Comment: I need to keep the content. What do you mean by using a property?

Comment: I get an error when trying using remove() on elem. Any solution?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: elem.remove is not a function
    at removeElement (script.js:43)
    at script.js:53
removeElement @ script.js:43
(anonymous) @ script.js:53

Comment: Now this shows up!
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
    at removeElement (script.js:44)
    at script.js:53